# How to check if two users have a common chat room?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, having-clause

Currently, I am trying to figure out how to find the common chat rooms between two users by checking their email addresses.

**chat_rooms table:**

```
id           email                chat_room_id  
----------------------------------------------
1          johndoe@gmail.com        3
2          janedoe@gmail.com        3
3          test@gmail.com           42
4          check@gmail.com          64
5          janedoe@gmail.com        7
6          test@gmail.com           19
7          johndoe@gmail.com        6
```

How can I write a MySQL query that can return the common `chat_room_id` of `johndoe@gmail.com` and `janedoe@gmail.com`. Please advise.

Comment: Do you know about joins and sub-queries?

Comment: @Evert, I am still learning how to join queries.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with aggregation:

```
select chat_room_id
from mytable
where email in ('johndoe@gmail.com', 'janedoe@gmail.com')
group by chat_room_id
having count(*) = 2
```

This assumes that the same user cannot appear twice in the same room. If that's not the case, then you would just change the `having` clause to:

```
having count(distinct email) = 2
```

Or:

```
having min(email) <> max(email)
```

Comment: `ahving` is under-used in my opoinon

Comment: This works! Thank you for you explanation and providing different cases as well! It really helped me understand better.